# How to extract a value of a http xml answer

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

Well I'm kinda new to C# and I'm trying to get a value of a http answer. But I never worked with that XML stuff before.

Easy example: http://freegeoip.net/xml/123.123.123.123

```
<Response>
<Ip>123.123.123.123</Ip>
<CountryCode>CN</CountryCode>
<CountryName>China</CountryName>
<RegionCode>22</RegionCode>
<RegionName>Beijing</RegionName>
<City>Beijing</City>
<ZipCode/>
<Latitude>39.9289</Latitude>
<Longitude>116.388</Longitude>
<MetroCode/>
</Response>
```

I want to return the `<CountryName></CountryName>` part in C#.
Any examples?

Comment: Search for linq to xml. You will find helpful examples

Comment: Might be useful to see your c# code as to how you're getting that response.  If it is dealing with XML have you tried googling c# xml samples? eg. http://www.csharp-examples.net/xml-nodes-by-name/ Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it one of two ways. The quick and dirty way is to simply search for CountryName in the XML string, but I doubt that's a particularly robust answer.

Caveating this response with the fact that the XML provided is not well-formed, I'll offer that the better answer for reading XML programmatically is in the System.Xml namespace, and using an XmlDocument object to load and parse the data:

```
using System.Xml;

public static void Main(String args[])
{
    XmlDocument foo = new XmlDocument();

    //Let's assume that the IP of the target player is in args[1]
    //This allows us to parameterize the Load method to reflect the IP address
    //of the user per the OP's request
    foo.Load( String.Format("http://freegeoip.net/xml/{0}",args[1])); 

    XmlNode root = foo.DocumentElement;

    // you might need to tweak the XPath query below
    XmlNode countryNameNode = root.SelectSingleNode("/Response/CountryName");

    Console.WriteLine(countryNameNode.InnerText);
}
```

That's not a 100% perfect solution, but it should represent a good start. Hope this helps.

Comment: It does work if I use a defined IP. But how can I use 2 arguments in Load?

e.g.
> XmlDocument locrequest = new XmlDocument();
> locrequest.Load("http://freegeoip.net/xml/{0}", player.IP);
> XmlNode root = locrequest.DocumentElement;
> string from = root.SelectSingleNode("CountryName").InnerText;

Comment: @IngoGuther See the amended answer to determine if I've answered your question.

Comment: I messed up that last comment... How can I format that? The `` does not work

Comment: It's harder to format code blocks in comments. No worries, I think I understand what you were asking.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm looking for (String.Format). Thanks !

Comment: Well I need more help with this. Now I'm getting some exceptions. See: http://pastebin.com/j7nV3W6W (System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Not enough buffer space is available))

Answer (score 0):

Use [XmlDocument.Load Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/875kz807.aspx) to get the document from the URL.

Then use [XmlNode.SelectNodes Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcebdtae.aspx) to get the node of your interest. For doing this, you need to use a simple [XPath Expression](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_examples.asp).

You can also use [LINQ2XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try this program.  Then you can access information through the response object.

```
public class Response
{
    public string Ip { get; set; }
    public string Countrycode { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public string RegionCode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
    public string Longitude { get; set; }
    public string MetroCode { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new System.Net.WebClient();

        string downloadedString = client.DownloadString("http://freegeoip.net/xml/123.123.123.123");

        XmlSerializer mySerializer =
            new XmlSerializer(typeof(Response));

        Response response = null;

        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new System.IO.StringReader(downloadedString));

        response = (Response)mySerializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);

    }
}
```