# XML Document System.Net.WebException

Tags: c#, exception

This part of my code throws an exception. How can I fix that?

```
XmlDocument locrequest = new XmlDocument();
locrequest.Load(String.Format("http://api.geoips.com/ip/{0}/key/.myapikey./output/xml/", player.IP));
XmlNode root = locrequest.DocumentElement;
string from = root.SelectSingleNode("country_name").InnerText.ToLower();
```

> System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Not enough buffer space is available)

Full error http://pastebin.com/8u6MpeWS

Edit:
If I add 
`locrequest.XmlResolver = null;`
it throws another exception:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

What's wrong with that?

Comment: Are you sure player.IP contains a valid IP address?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WebRequest` class in order to load file

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("...");
// If required by the server, set the credentials.
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
// Get the response.
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();
// Display the status.
Console.WriteLine (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
// Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
.....
```

Comment: @Ingo, you can take the dataStream object created here in Aghilas' response and pass it as a parameter to the overloaded Load method in the XmlDocument class, eg XmlDocument locRequest = new XmlDocument(); locRequest.Load(dataStream);

Answer (score 0):

Building on Aghilas' post...

The returned stream is a non-seekable stream, so you need to read to the end of it using a function similar to the following:

```
static byte[] readFullStream(Stream st)
    {
        Array Buffer = (byte[])Array.CreateInstance(typeof(byte), 32768);
        System.Int32 Size;
        bool eof = false;
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        while (!eof)
        {
            Size = st.Read((byte[])Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);
            if (Size > 0)
            {
                ms.Write((byte[])Buffer, 0, Size);
            }
            else
            {
                eof = true;
            }
        }
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```

Then once you have the byte array from the function above, load up your XmlDocument with it.

Remember, we're starting from the bottom of Aghilas' code...

```
byte[] buffer = readFullStream(dataStream);
XmlDocument locrequest = new XmlDocument();
locrequest.LoadXML(new UFT8Encoding().GetString(buffer));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ingo,

Building on your original post for this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504562/how-to-extract-a-value-of-a-http-xml-answer/12504707), perhaps this will put the pieces together for you a bit more clearly. Assuming that there is something more basic at hand for the connection failures than just that the server is, for whatever reason, not accepting connections, you can bypass the default Load() mechanism of the XmlDocument class by using, as Aghilas pointed out, a WebRequest object.

A WebRequest object contacts the URL you specify, and then uses the Request/Response model to create a Response object. From that Response object, you can get a *stream* to the data for the response via the GetResponseStream() method; that's what Aghilas demonstrated. You can then take that stream, placed in the variable dataStream in his sample, and pass that to the overload for the XmlDocument.Load() method that expects a Stream:

```
   //assuming prior code from Aghilas is here as appropriate...
   Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
   XmlDocument locRequest = new XmlDocument();
   locRequest.Load(dataStream);
```

Hope this helps.